# No test/scenrios are collected when multiple tags are using in @cucumberoptions

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

When i use multiple tags in @CucumberOptions, TestRunner doesn't collect any test, though, it works fine when i only use one tag like:

> @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features", glue =
>   {"stepDefinitions"}, tags = {"@smoke"})

Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong in the below code? I've also attached the dependence using in pom.xml, if anyone wants to see the version.

**I have tried possible existing answers on StackOverflow, but none of them worked**

Place.feature

```
Feature: Some feature

  @smoke
  Scenario: Verify AddPlaceAPI
    Given Add place payload
    When User calls "AddPlaceAPI" using HTTP "post" request
    Then API call is a success with status code 200

  @regression
  Scenario: Verify place is deleted successfully using DeletePlaceAPI
    Given DeletePlace payload
    When User calls "DeletePlaceAPI" using HTTP "post" request
    Then API call is a success with status code 200
```

TestRunner.java

```
package cucumber.Options;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features", glue = {"stepDefinitions"}, tags = {"@smoke,@regression"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Pom.xml

```
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also tried using two different cmd's but that none of them worked:

```
mvn clean  test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke,@regression"
or
mvn clean  test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke,@regression"
```

Comment: Use `"@smoke or @regression"`. Use 'and', 'or' and 'not'. Older syntax is deprecated.

Comment: @Grasshopper Awesome, it worked. Thank you so much.